# Is there any planetary arrangement described for end of the world in Hindu scriptures?

Tags: scripture, astrology

Is there any planetary arrangement described for the end of the world in Hindu scriptures? If yes then please describe.

Comment: Do you want the planetary configuration of the end of the Kali Yuga or the Pralaya or the Mahapralaya or what?

Comment: We, humans, are small windows, we do not know more before and after life. So I asked this question. Sorry if anybody gets hurt.

Comment: Technically all the planets should merge to each other during end of the universe. Just before that, they should be indeed very close to each other or may be already destroyed.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi - IMO the destroyer aspect of God will definitely  show some signs to living beings ( if survives) before starting of the actual destruction process.Or that might have already been started as we can see and feel negative impacts like "Global warmimg" etc. I think the destruction process will be extermely slow , and no living thing anywhere in universe will actual witness the last moment.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi - and that process will continue for  very long time , after ending of all life forms in the universe.

Comment: There's a distinction between end of the world as we know it (civilizational breakdown), end of humans as a species (biological annihilation) and end of the physical universe (a heat death sorts of situation). Which one are you hinting at?

Comment: Guys be serius, Setu Organization claims that Lord Hanuman has told that all the material of the world will melt and destruction will be enforced to this world. Please visit its web site to know more(setuu.org). I just want to know planetary situations so that we can know the time left for us to pray to Supreme Lord.

Comment: We are not advocates who see is it true or not, we are devotees who want liberation before destruction. If you are in, go on else be where you are. Sorry if I have hurt you.

Answer (score 1):

If referring to end of kaliyug

And then when the Sun, the Moon, and Vrihaspati will, with the constellation Pushya, enter the same sign, the Krita age will begin again.

Mahabharat vana parva,Section CLXXXIX